# pandas: Calculate time difference between column values of two different dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have 2 DataFrames one contain Login and logout times and other contains event details. I need to calculate time difference between the events on per day basis also considering their login and logout times.

df1:

```
+------+-----------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------+
|  Id  |            Start            | PersonId |             End             | ShiftId |
+------+-----------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------+
| 3258 | 2019-09-24 08:15:03.1661178 |    10102 | 2019-09-24 08:28:10.7341840 |     191 |
| 3262 | 2019-09-24 08:40:07.8842560 |    10102 | 2019-09-24 09:00:57.9763744 |     191 |
| 3268 | 2019-09-24 10:14:18.2592931 |    10102 | 2019-09-24 10:32:38.8476858 |     191 |
| 3272 | 2019-09-24 11:57:49.3470913 |    10102 | 2019-09-24 12:09:06.1498356 |     191 |
| 3280 | 2019-09-24 14:10:53.2358758 |    10102 | 2019-09-24 14:38:43.6855268 |     191 |
| 3287 | 2019-09-25 04:44:18.8789158 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 05:27:31.7607861 |     201 |
| 3291 | 2019-09-25 06:21:27.9382344 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 06:29:34.5009788 |     201 |
| 3293 | 2019-09-25 06:50:58.7228054 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 07:33:53.7195993 |     201 |
| 3309 | 2019-09-25 11:33:55.5238972 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 11:48:11.8716401 |     201 |
| 3313 | 2019-09-25 11:55:09.3772345 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 12:11:01.2300854 |     201 |
| 3319 | 2019-09-25 12:44:19.3644289 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 13:32:34.4384967 |     201 |
| 3323 | 2019-09-25 14:37:28.4818603 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 15:06:48.5209333 |     201 |
+------+-----------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------+
```

df2:

```
+----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
| PersonId |          LoginTime          |         LogoutTime          |
+----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
|    10102 | 2019-09-24 05:07:27.3883395 | 2019-09-24 15:49:07.4924940 |
|    10102 | 2019-09-25 03:25:32.8983664 | 2019-09-25 15:54:45.5404037 |
|    10102 | 2019-09-26 02:28:53.1234933 | 2019-09-26 15:00:10.1138188 |
+----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

Desired Output:

```
+------+-----------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------+------------+
|  Id  |            Start            | PersonId |             End             | ShiftId |   After    |
+------+-----------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------+------------+
| 3258 | 2019-09-24 08:15:03.1661178 |    10102 | 2019-09-24 08:28:10.7341840 |     191 | 188 mins   |--> df1[start]-df2[logon] of same date
| 3262 | 2019-09-24 08:40:07.8842560 |    10102 | 2019-09-24 09:00:57.9763744 |     191 | 12min      |
| 3268 | 2019-09-24 10:14:18.2592931 |    10102 | 2019-09-24 10:32:38.8476858 |     191 | 14 min     |
| 3272 | 2019-09-24 11:57:49.3470913 |    10102 | 2019-09-24 12:09:06.1498356 |     191 | 85 min     |
| 3280 | 2019-09-24 14:10:53.2358758 |    10102 | 2019-09-24 14:38:43.6855268 |     191 | 71 min     |
| 3287 | 2019-09-25 04:44:18.8789158 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 05:27:31.7607861 |     201 | 79min      |
| 3291 | 2019-09-25 06:21:27.9382344 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 06:29:34.5009788 |     201 | 54 min     |
| 3293 | 2019-09-25 06:50:58.7228054 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 07:33:53.7195993 |     201 | 21min      |
| 3309 | 2019-09-25 11:33:55.5238972 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 11:48:11.8716401 |     201 | 4 hrs      |
| 3313 | 2019-09-25 11:55:09.3772345 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 12:11:01.2300854 |     201 | 7 min      |
| 3319 | 2019-09-25 12:44:19.3644289 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 13:32:34.4384967 |     201 | 33mins     |
| 3323 | 2019-09-25 14:37:28.4818603 |    10102 | 2019-09-25 15:06:48.5209333 |     201 | 65mins     |
+------+-----------------------------+----------+-----------------------------+---------+------------+
```

Basically trying to calculate difference between the event e.g. 1st event occurs 188min after logon and 2nd occurs after  12 min but on per day basis.
My approach was to use for loop with an array of days and months. It worked fine but was slow, messy. need pandas approach to get desired output.
what I have tried so, far is this:

```
df1['Date']=df1['End'].dt.date
df1['Day'] = df1['End'].dt.day
df1['f']=df1.groupby(['PersonId', 'Day'])['Start'].shift(-1)-df1['End']
df1['f']=df1['f'].shift()
```

this will give me time in between the events of the df1, but now how to calculate the time difference between `longon and first event` and `last event and logout`
Any Help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do we need `df2`? Probably I missed something. Also, any reason you can't simply subtract `Start` from `End` to get desired output?

Comment: @LukaszTracewski no need for df2 if you want to join them, go ahead. and then calculate the difference, subtracting the start and end will give only time between the same event not time between two events.

Comment: can  you provide us with  your row data as json, or as df?

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb if you need the above dataframes you can use `df = pd.read_clipboard()`, just copy paste above dfs to a clipboard and use this

Comment: @tsu90280  please when writing a question, it must be easy to replicate, so we can help you faster.